# Proof involving a vacuously true statement

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be a finite subset of a metric space. Show that it is closed.

I know a set is closed if and only if it contains all of its accumulation points. Let $x$ be an accumulation point of $S$. I want to show that $x \in S$. Since $S$ is a finite set, I know that it cannot have a accumulation point. So does this imply that $x \in S$ and I am done with the proof?

If I have made an error, could someone explain?

Comment: What do you know of topology? There are spaces where finite subsets need not be closed, but of course not metric spaces.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I'm doing exercises on metric spaces in a real analysis book. And I've never taken a class on topology.

Comment: Ah, since I won't fit a topology course in the comments, take my word for it, it's not vacuously true. There is something to show. It's very easy though.

Comment: What is the definition of accumulation point in your course?

Comment: @DanielFischer: $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$ if every $n$-ball $B(x)$ contains at least one point of $S$ distinct from $x$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. And from that definition, how do you know that a finite set has no accumulation points?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Suppose a finite set has an accumulation point. Then take the minimum distance between all the points and the accumulation point. Consider a ball with half that distance. It will contain no points and that will be a contradiction.

Comment: And there's your proof. (You need to exclude the putative accumulation point from the distances if it is in $S$.)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Let me see if I understand you. Since $S$ contains all its accumulation points (since it has none) that means $S$ is closed. Right?

Comment: Right. But that it has no accumulation points is something that needs to be proved.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks I get it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $S$ is closed in a metric space $M$, it is enough to show that $S$ contains all its accumulation points.

Since $S$ is finite, we can show that it has no accumulation points. Proof by contradiction: suppose that $S$ has an accumulation point $x$. Consider $r = \min |x-y|$ for all $y \in S$. Then the ball around $x$ with radius $r/2$ will contain no points of $S$. So $S$ contains no accumulation points.

Since $S$ contains all of its accumulation points (since $S$ has none), that means $S$ is closed in $M$.

Comment: The proof is correct, but it isn't really by contradiction since you never use the assumption that $S$ has an accumulation point. Also you suppose that $x$ is not in $S$ but that's okay since you only need to show that a point outside of $S$ is not an accumulation point.

Comment: @StefanH.: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that finite subsets contain interior points .But for a finite subset  we can find a least distance i.e we can find a ball around any point which contains no points of the set ,so no point is an interior point.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked almost a year ago; I wanted, however, to propose an alternate solution.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $S$ be a finite subset of $X$, say $S=\{x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\}$. A set is closed if its complement is open. So, we shall show that $X\backslash S$ is open. Pick an arbitrary point $x \in X \backslash S$. Let $r=\min\{d(x_{i},x): i=1, \ldots, n\}$. ( Note that $d(x_{i},x) \neq 0$ for each $i=1, \ldots, n$. Hence, $r > 0$. ) Then $B(x;r)$ is an open ball containing $x$ that lies entirely in $X\backslash S$. That is, $X\backslash S$ is a neighborhood of each of its points (because $x$ was arbitrary). We conclude $X\backslash S$ is open; it follows that $S$ is closed.